How big is the class of all closed range bounded linear operator?
Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and let $CR(X,Y)$ denote the set $B(X,Y)$ of all bounded linear maps from $X$ to $Y$ with $T(X)$ closed in $Y$. Certainly $CR(X,Y)$ is not open in $B(X,Y)$ as given any $T\in B(X,Y)$ whose range is not closed, $\|\frac{1}{n}T-0\|\to 0$ and $0$ is a closed range operator. Also $CR(X,Y)$ is not closed in $B(X,Y)$ as if $Y$ has the approximation property, every compact operator from $X$ to $Y$ can be approximated by finite rank operators (obviously in $CR(X,Y)$). Now the question is the following:
Is $CR(X,Y)$ dense in $B(X,Y)$? Can every bounded linear operator from $X$ to $Y$ be approximated by a closed range operator? Any hint or suggestion is appreciated.

The answer is no in general. There are Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that every closed range operator from $X$ to $Y$ is finite rank, but not every operator from $X$ to $Y$ is approximable by finite rank operators.
For example, let $1<p<q<\infty$, $X=\ell_p$, $Y=\ell_q$, and let $T\in B(X,Y)$ have closed range. If $T(X)$ were infinite dimensional, then $\ell_q$ would be isomorphic to a quotient of $\ell_p$ since $\ell_q$ (and its subspace $T(X)$) is complementably $\ell_q$-saturated. But (as is well known) $\ell_q$ is not isomorphic to a quotient of $\ell_p$, so it must be that $T(X)$ is finite dimensional.
Thus, for a counterexample you can take any non-compact operator from $\ell_p$ to $\ell_q$, where $1<p<q<\infty$. For instance, take $T$ to be the formal identity map.

Is there a positive answer for pairs $(X,Y)$ for which $X$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $Y$?
